# Leaking goroutine when a non-blocking readline hangs

Tags: go, goroutine

Assuming you have a structure like this:

```
ch := make(chan string)
errCh := make(chan error)
go func() {
    line, _, err := bufio.NewReader(r).ReadLine()
    if err != nil {
        errCh <- err
    } else {
        ch <- string(line)
    }
}()
select {
case err := <-errCh:
    return "", err
case line := <-ch:
    return line, nil
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    return "", TimeoutError
}
```

In the case of the 5 second timeout, the goroutine hangs until ReadLine returns, which may never happen. My project is a long-running server, so I don't want a buildup of stuck goroutines.

Comment: From what are you reading in variable `r` (Internet, Disk, Cluster) ?

Comment: Why do you think `ReadLine` may never return? Where are you reading from that there is no timeout procedure?

Comment: I'm reading `r` from exec.Command.StdoutPipe()

Comment: Are you expecting hung execution or empty output on your exec calls?  Using exec.Command.Output() in that goroutine would collect the output and throw an error if the exec.Command didn't execute without blocking the rest of the program.

Comment: `.Output()` runs a program and waits for it to exit, but I don't want to wait for the program to exit. The master program is starting another process. This process is expected to print a line to stdout when it is ready.

Comment: Bravada, yes I want the process to continue running after the readline or timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadLine will not return until either the process exits or the method reads a line. There's no deadline or timeout mechanism for pipes.

The goroutine will block if the call to ReadLine returns after the timeout. This can be fixed by using buffered channels:

```
ch := make(chan string, 1)
errCh := make(chan error, 1)
```

The application should call [Wait](http://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Wait) to cleanup resources associated with the command. The goroutine is a good place to call it:

```
go func() {
  line, _, err := bufio.NewReader(r).ReadLine()
  if err != nil {
    errCh <- err
  } else {
    ch <- string(line)
  }
  cmd.Wait() // <-- add this line
}()
```

This will cause the goroutine to block, the very thing you are trying to avoid. The alternative is that the application leaks resources for each command.

Comment: That fixed my problem.  I was trying all kinds of ways to close the reader, kill the process, etc. I didn't realize the goroutine was blocking when it tried to write to `errCh`

Comment: Ps. Can i add `cmd.Release()` instead of `Wait()`?

Comment: @Gattster What is cmd.Release()?

Comment: sorry, I meant `cmd.Process.Release()`. https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Release

Comment: Process.Release does not cleanup the resources use by Command.

Comment: I don't want to kill the process, but I do want the program that created the process to release all info about it and let the GC throw it away. Isn't that what release does?

"Release releases any resources associated with the Process p, rendering it unusable in the future. Release only needs to be called if Wait is not."

Comment: Command.StdoutPipe opens an os.Pipe.  The read end of the pipe is closed in Command.Wait.  The application leaks fd if Wait is not called.

Comment: So Command.Release() is what I need to call if no .Wait(), right?

Comment: There is no Command.Release. To release the file descriptors allocated by Command, you must call Command.Wait.